# How to display a default value for minute field of Time fieldtype

Tags: entities, webforms

I have a **Time** component in my [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform). When I go to my form I see **Hour** is selected by default in the **Hour** field but I see **00** is selected by default in the **Minute** field.

How I can set **Minute** as the default value in the **Minute** field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the time component says in its description field, it "accepts a time in any [GNU Date Input Format](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/tar_7.html#Date-input-formats). Strings such as now, +2 hours, and 10:30pm are all valid."

If you want to set the default minute, you can used a formatted string like "1972-09-24T20:02:00,000000-0500" or "10:30pm" in the **Default value** field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to a bug I just reported here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2663960

Try to modify the following file: sites/all/modules/webform/components/time.inc by looking for:

```
$default_values = array(
  'hour' => '',
  'minute' => '0',
  'second' => '',
);
```

(line 191) and change it to:

```
$default_values = array(
  'hour' => '',
  'minute' => '',
  'second' => '',
);
```

Keep your eye on the link I posted above to see the official resolution of this issue.